# Integral versus Riemann's sum

Tags: calculus

Why is it that this integral

$$    \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x = 1$$

does not equal the Riemann sum,

$$    \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} = \pi^2/6?$$

Comment: That is not the Riemann sum of the integral.

Comment: is it because the integral sums up all the decimals and whole numbers from 1 to infinity, where as the sum only sums up whole numbers?

Comment: Basically yes, the sum is summing up through the integers from 1 to infinity, that is rectangles of width 1. The integral is summing up rectangles of infinitesimal width.

Comment: Actually, I tend to ask the other way round - why should the integral be equal to the sum? The way the question is posed is sort of incomprehensible to me.

Comment: The Riemann sum would be more like $$\lim_{\Delta x\mathop\to0}\Delta x\sum_{k\mathop=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+k\Delta x)^2}=1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riemann sum is
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}f(x_k)\Delta x_k$$
Therefore, the Riemann sum should be
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\dfrac{\Delta x_k}{(x_k)^2}$$
When you let $(x_k)=(1,2,...)$, then $\Delta x_k=1$, and so, the Riemann sum indeed becomes
$$\sum^\infty_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}=\pi^2/6$$
Note however, that the integral takes $\lim\Delta x_k\to0$, but you are taking $\Delta x_k=1$, which is a bigger interval than $1$. Hence, your sum will not be *very* accurate - in fact,
$$\left|\int^\infty_1\dfrac{dx}{x^2}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\dfrac{1}{k^2}\right|=0.64493406684$$
Which is kind of close to $0$. When $\lim\Delta x_k\to0$, $\left|\int^\infty_1\dfrac{dx}{x^2}-\lim_{\Delta x_k\to0}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\dfrac{\Delta x_k}{(x_k)^2}\right|\to0$.

Comment: Might want to pick some absolute value signs in there - the integral is smaller than that sum.